# How do I consume an array of arrays using org.json?

Tags: java

how do i consume this json using org.json?

```
{
    "links": [
        [
            "a0b7a44b-333a-4ad8-aa1c-6689bb6265e5",
            {
                "label": "main",
                "currency": "GHS"
            }
        ],
        [
            "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000200",
            {
                "label": "main",
                "currency": "GHS"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

it appears to be an array of one-item arrays and i can't figure out how to unpack it.

Edit:

I see this question:

[How to parse a json array with an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721149/how-to-parse-a-json-array-with-an-array-of-arrays?rq=1)

that person is using gson, i'm using org.json.  also the accepted answer to that question is:

> Try using this:
>
> ```
> private List<List<Object>> f = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
> ```
>
> And then f.get(0).get(0) will give you a String of "type", and
>   f.get(0).get(1) will give you a JsonObject
>
> http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html

- i don't know how to get the data in to f
- the link is broken

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721149/how-to-parse-a-json-array-with-an-array-of-arrays?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse a json array with an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721149/how-to-parse-a-json-array-with-an-array-of-arrays)

Comment: many thanks for getting back to me.  it's not the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this did the trick.

```
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(inputString);

        JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("links");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println(arr.getString(i));
            JSONArray arr2 =arr.getJSONArray(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < arr2.length(); j++) {
                System.out.println(arr2.getString(j));
            }
            String s1 = arr2.getString(0);
            System.out.println(s1);
            JSONObject obj2 =arr2.getJSONObject(1);
            String s2 = obj2.getString("label");
            System.out.println(s2);
            String s3 = obj2.getString("currency");
            System.out.println(s3);
        }
```